# Trouble with swap method

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, swap

I've got an issue with a swap method I'm trying to write. I'm convinced it's this section of code as it only throws an exception when the program terminates if these lines are uncommented. Comment them out and the file terminates properly.
My classes and the function I'm having problems with are below.

```
class WordOccurrence {
public:
    //Constructor
    WordOccurrence(const std::string& word = "", int num = 0) { num_ = num; word_ = word; };

    //Member Functions
    bool matchWord(const std::string &); // returns true if word matches stored
    void increment(); // increments number of occurrences

    //Accessors
    std::string getWord() const;
    int getNum() const;

private:
    std::string word_;
    int num_;
};

//Bag
class WordList {
    public:
        //Big 3:
        WordList(int size = 0) { size_ = size; wordArray_ = size>0 ? new     WordOccurrence[size] : nullptr;};
        ~WordList() { delete[] wordArray_; };
        WordList(const WordList& list);

        //Assignment Overload
        WordList& operator =(const WordList& source);

        //Member Functions
        void addWord(const std::string &word);
        friend void swap(WordOccurrence& first, WordOccurrence& second);

        //  void swap(WordOccurrence& lhs, WordOccurrence& rhs);
        void sortList();
        void printList();
    private:
        WordOccurrence *wordArray_; // a dynamically allocated array of WordOccurrences  
                            // may or may not be sorted
        int size_;
};
```

and the sort function containing swap:

```
void WordList::sortList() {
for (int i = 0; i < size_; ++i) {
    for (int j = size_; j > i; --j) {
        if (wordArray_[j].getNum() < wordArray_[j - 1].getNum()) {
            WordOccurrence tmp(wordArray_[j].getWord(), wordArray_[j].getNum());  //problem is
        //  tmp = wordArray_[j];                          // is 
            wordArray_[j] = wordArray_[j-1];              // in 
            wordArray_[j-1] = tmp;                        // here
            //swap(wordArray_[j], wordArray_[j - 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

I tried initializing 'tmp' to an empty object as well but that didn't make a difference either.
I also tried std::swap and it's throws the same "triggered a breakpoint" error when the program terminates. Again, the error disappears if I comment out the problem lines. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From examination of the code, the `size_` member specifies the size of the dynamically-allocated `wordArray_`.

```
for (int j = size_; j > i; --j) {
    if (wordArray_[j].getNum() < wordArray_[j - 1].getNum()) {
```

This is going to run off past the end of the array, resulting in undefined behavior, and the likely crash.

`j` starts off being equal to `size_`. Since `size_` is the actual size of `wordArray_`, and `wordArray_` contains elements numbered 0 through `size_-1`, then `wordArray_[j]`, on the first iteration, does not exist. That's your bug.

Comment: Thanks! I should have caught that but I was convinced it had something to do with the objects being different sizes that was causing the issue.